# Catkin unable to include custom libraries

Tags: ros, catkin, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package `proj_util` which is using the following catkin files, which seem to correctly generate the libraries and put them into `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib`.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(proj_util)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES visionutil rosutil
)

ADD_LIBRARY(visionutil src/math.cpp src/math.hpp)
ADD_LIBRARY(rosutil src/rosutil.cpp src/rosutil.hpp)
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>proj_util</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Package for utility libraries</description>

  <maintainer email="ras@todo.todo">me</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>opencv2</buildtool_depend>
  <run_depend>opencv2</run_depend>  

  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

However, when I try and use the libraries in another package, compilation crashes, stating that the header file cannot be found. The CMakeLists.txt for the package in which I want to use the libraries look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(motor_controller2)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs ras_arduino_msgs proj_util)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs ras_arduino_msgs proj_util
)


include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(motor_controller2 src/motorController2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(motor_controller2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rosutil)
add_dependencies(motor_controller2 ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

I added references to the `proj_util` package to anywhere where it seemed relevant, but it didn't seem to make any difference. I also tried using the names of the libraries instead, but to no avail.

I've tried using numerous variations on `#include <rosutil/rosutil.hpp>`, but none of them seem to work. I tried using

```
catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES visionutil rosutil
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
)
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
```

as recommended by [this](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_libraries.html) tutorial on building libraries, but even with this nothing seems to change.

I've tried to locate the files generated by the CMakeLists.txt for the library package, and other than the files used by make, the only files are `librosutil.so` and `libvisionutil.so`, located in `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib`. Specifically, there are no references in any include directory to these library files.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195467/catkin-unable-to-include-custom-libraries/) by [heuristicus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20537/heuristicus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way is to have the package export its include directory as Gary mentioned. The install() call is not really necessary.

You should create a folder named **include/ < name of package > /** (include/proj_utils in your case) where you put all the header files (*.hpp) of the package.

Then the package that exports the library should have the following in the CMakeLists to be able to export the header files:

```
catkin_package(
      LIBRARIES visionutil rosutil
      INCLUDE_DIRS include)

include_directories(
   include
   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Then the other package should be able to see the header files as (you might have to run catkin_make or cmake first):

```
 #include <name_of_package/header_file.h>
```

In your case:

```
#include <proj_util/rosutil.hpp>
```

---

Originally posted by [Francisco Vina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2813/francisco-vina/) with karma: 101 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4